# shell command stdout event in Python

Tags: python, stdout

I'm trying to watch wifi network changes from Python. So there is `iwevent` which is a part of [wireless_tools](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/wireless_tools/) on Linux to watch events. Every time I'm switching wifi, `iwevent` prints out following output

```
03:33:33.082474   wlan0    New Access Point/Cell address:Not-Associated
03:33:33.168659   wlan0    Scan request completed
03:33:33.234036   wlan0    Association Request IEs:00...
03:33:33.234109   wlan0    Association Response IEs:01...
03:33:33.234171   wlan0    New Access Point/Cell address:F...
```

So is there a way I can do this in an event driven way where Python watching `stdout` in a thread and when it gets new `stdout` it's doing to trigger a method?

Comment: If you start `iwevent` via `subprocess.Popen` then you can specify `stdout` to be redirected to a pipe. Then you can have a thread do a blocking read on this pipe. Whenever there is something to read, the thread will wake up. You may have issues with pipe buffers, though. The data may get buffered in the pipe and you may see the data only in larger chunks. Some answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394804/is-there-a-command-similar-to-iwevent-to-monitor-eth0-state give a more direct way to monitor the state: watch the state/content of a file.

Answer (score 0):

Wich wireless tool are you using, can you tell ?

Or, please, check if you could setting up a file to write log, instead to use `sys.stdout`.
I think you can configure it by params (even using **args* or ***kwargs*)

OR If ou have access to the code (of the your wireless-tools), you can easily do it by:

> sys.stdout = open("/path/MyFileStdout.log", "w")

And every print in your program will be written to the file, and you can monitoring the file easily, using `python-watchdog` library, a straightforward Python API library to monitor file system events, like these examples:

1. https://blog.magrathealabs.com/filesystem-events-monitoring-with-python-9f5329b651c3
2. http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

I hope this can help you, or, please, give us more information about your environment.

Best wishes!

Comment: it's https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/wireless_tools/. updated the question too

Comment: https://github.com/HewlettPackard/wireless-tools/blob/master/wireless_tools/iwevent.c